# Is it possible/workable to store a large (1 hr MP3) in an offline cache for a web app?

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, offline-caching, offlineapps

I need to be able to create a way of delivering a web app which includes being able to play a long - up to 1hr MP3 file without having to be connected to the internet.

The end user would be a tourist who would incur roaming charges if the gprs internet were used. The idea is that it can be preloaded while the user has access to wifi (e.g. in the hotel). They can then go out and about and still use the application and access the audio content.

Of course one way would be to provide it as an iPhone app/android, but I wondered whether there could be another way? Perhaps through writing a suitable web app using Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no reliable way to this, although it may work on Google Chrome.
e.g. - 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

But the specifications are DEAD
 [W3C - [fileapi-directories-and-system/filewriter]](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2014AprJun/0010.html)